# Syntax error in mysql stored procedure calling from EF 6

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am calling a stored procedure from MVC 5 application with Entity Framework 6. It is throwing this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rv_test_param 1' at line 1

My code is:

```
var res = Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("rv_test_param @id", new MySqlParameter("@id", 1)).ToList();
```

The stored procedure is working fine. If I call stop without parameters

Like this:

```
var redf = Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("rv_test").ToList();
```

it also works fine. Does Anyone have an idea why it is not working with parameters?

Comment: Could it be the issues with permissions? Not with EF but when using ADO .NET, I have seen errors complaining about parameters when running through app, but sp by itself running fine. In my case, they were SQL permission related issues.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @NoSaidTheCompiler but this time issue was wrong syntex. I got it working by changing my calling syntex. Check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax mistake. I'm from a SQL Server background, so I was not aware of these syntaxes. This is working for me:

```
var res = Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("call rv_test_param(@id)", new MySqlParameter("@id", 1)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime CurrentDateStarts = (DateTime)dtBegin.Value;

DateTime CurrentDateEnds = (DateTime)dtEnd.Value;

CurrentDateStarts = (new DateTime(CurrentDateStarts.Year, CurrentDateStarts.Month, CurrentDateStarts.Day));

CurrentDateEnds = (new DateTime(CurrentDateEnds.Year, CurrentDateEnds.Month, CurrentDateEnds.Day)).AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
            //

geststokv1Entities2 con = geststokv1Entities2.newInstance; 

var produit = cmbProduct.SelectedItem.ListObject as stock_produit; 

var result = con.Database.SqlQuery<view_articleanalysis>("call get_articleanalysis(@produit_id)", new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@produit_id", produit.PRODUIT_ID)).ToList();


var list = result.Where(x =>  x.FREE_QUANTITY > 0
             && x.Date_validation >= CurrentDateStarts
             && x.Date_validation <= CurrentDateEnds
            ).ToList();


UGFree.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it another way, e.g:

```
 db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CALL GenarateTable(@tablename)", new MySqlParameter("@tablename", tenantDetail.tablename));
```